# Use Sqlite group_concat in db.query() instead of rawquery

Tags: android, android-sqlite

What is the equivalent for db.query() of following query:
**select group_concat(Id, ',') as ids from RECORD_MASTER**

Its working fine with rawquery() but I want to implement it in query() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
db.query(
    DATABASE_TABLE,
    new String [] {"group_concat(Id, ',') as ids"}, 
    null, null, null, null, null
);
```

which corresponds to this function declaration:

```
Cursor query (String table, 
    String[] columns, 
    String selection, 
    String[] selectionArgs, 
    String groupBy, 
    String having, 
    String orderBy)
```